# Как получить коллекцию связанных данных выбранного элемента в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При получении выбранного элемента с `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0" />
```

.

```
 private Group selectedGroup;

    public Group SelectedGroup  
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedGroup ;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedGroup  = value ;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }
```

он возвращает только первый элемент

```
<Grid   Grid.Row="1"     DataContext="{Binding SelectedGroup.PupilGroups}" >
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Pupil.FirstName}"  ></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

а мне нужно что бы он вернул все данные связанные с выбранным элементом 
связь между таблицами  многие ко многим

```
Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>(_db.Groups.Include(bb=>bb.PupilGroups).ThenInclude(bb=>bb.Pupil).ToList());
```

Comment: А по другому и быть не может, если вы привязываетесь таким образом `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Pupil.FirstName}" `. Для листбокса источником должна быть коллекция, а у вас фамилия одного ученика.

Comment: @Bulson  ,а как быть ? Нужно создать отдельный метод toString в модели Pupil ? Для возвращения значений?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Canvas>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Category}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
              Canvas.Left="33"
              Canvas.Top="41"
              Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Категория"
           Canvas.Left="33"
           Canvas.Top="10" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupPersons}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
             Height="85"
             Canvas.Left="33"
             Canvas.Top="89"
             Width="466" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedGroup}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             Height="100"
             Canvas.Left="33"
             Canvas.Top="196"
             Width="466" />
</Canvas>
```

Вьюмодель такая

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private const string _CATEGORY_1 = " ";
    private const string _CATEGORY_2 = "Ученики";
    private const string _CATEGORY_3 = "Учителя";

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }


    public List<string> Category { get; set; } = new List<string> { _CATEGORY_1, _CATEGORY_2, _CATEGORY_3 };

    private string _SelectedCategory;
    public string SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return _SelectedCategory; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedCategory)));
            ShowCategory(); // присвоение значения GroupPersons
        }
    }

    private List<Group> _GroupPersons;
    public List<Group> GroupPersons
    {
        get { return _GroupPersons; }
        set
        {
            _GroupPersons = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(GroupPersons)));
        }
    }

    private Group _SelectedGroup;
    public Group SelectedGroup
    {
        get { return _SelectedGroup; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedGroup = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedGroup)));
        }
    }


    private void ShowCategory()
    {
        if (SelectedCategory.Equals(_CATEGORY_1))
        {
            GroupPersons = null;
        }
        else if (SelectedCategory.Equals(_CATEGORY_2))
        {
            GroupPersons = DataService.GetPupilGroups();
        }
        else
        {
            GroupPersons = DataService.GetTutorGroups();
        }
    }
}
```